# Printing out numbers as hexidecimal numbers

Tags: c, printf, hex

So I have the number 12 how do I printout it out in the format

```
0x0000000C // where there is always the 0x in the beginning and always 8 digits after to 
           // represent the number

fprintf(outputFile, "%x", 12);
```

is giving me:

```
cc
```

But I want:

```
0x0000000C
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

need to prefix 0x  and then Capital X to get the Capital C  and 08 says prefix with 0s to make up to 8 characters

```
fprintf(outputFile, "0x%08X", 12);
```

Answer (score 4):

`%08x`

will give you the right number of digits.  Just put the `0x` in front as decoration.

`%08X` will print the letters as caps.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
int x;
x=12;

printf("%#010x\n",x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fprintf(outputFile, "%#.8x", 12);
```

The `#` flag specifies the alternate form, which prepends `0x` with the `x` format.  The `.8` specifies a precision of 8, which is the minimum number of digits to appear for the `x` format.